# Testing Authentication to Dynamics CRM OData service

Tags: oauth, odata, dynamics-crm, adfs

I work on an application that can use OAuth to Authenticate it's self to a CRM OData service. It takes as arguments Client Id, Redirect Uri(because it is a desktop application this is usually localhost), Resource, and Authority Uri.

Is there a tool I can use to test to verify that CRM and ADFS are properly configured to allow my application to access the Odata service?

Comment: A question like this, requesting that we recommend a tool to verify CRM/ADFS configuration is likely to solicit a number of strong opinions from the community who may favor one tool over the other. A general guide is to avoid such questions and rather ask a more specific question about a problem you are encountering. For further details - please look at ["what types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).